# How to get current StatefulKnowledgeSession form list of StatefulKnowledgeSessions in ProcessEventListener in jbpm5?

Tags: jbpm

My requirement is  when Jbpm workflow process completed then i want close a session in `afterProcessCompleted()` of ProcessEventListener so now the question is how to get current StatefulKnowledgeSession from list of StatefulKnowledgeSessions.

Example :

```
afterProcessCompleted(){

//Get list of StatefulKnowledgeSessions.  

//want current StatefulKnowledgeSession.

}
```

Please give your valuble answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the `org.kie.api.event.process.ProcessEvent` in a parameter called `event`, have you tried:

`org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessInstance pi =(org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessInstance)event.getProcessInstance();
org.kie.internal.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession session=(org.kie.internal.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession)pi.getKnowledgeRuntime();`

Try it and let's see if it works. (I have a suspicion that at the afterProcessCompleted event the association between the processInstance and knowledgeRuntime may already have been severed, so I am quite keen to see if it works for you)